# Spring REST consuming JSON uppercase vs lowercase

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am trying to create simple webservice, that is reading JSON from URL and gives it back. I followed spring.io tutorial about this. I am probably missing something about naming conventions?

JSON I use doesn't have nice naming convention. Some values are in uppercase, some lowercase other are mixed. What I understood for proper matching with restTemplate I need to follow these names.

My object structure:

```
public class Page {
private String name; //works
private String about; // works
private String PHONE; //does not work
private String Website; //does not work

//getters and setters
}
```

If I change them to public, they start to work.

```
public class Page {
private String name; //works
private String about; // works
public String PHONE; //works
public String Website; //works

//getters and setters
}
```

This is the part of code where I use that

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Test")
public Bubble getBubbleInfo(){
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Page page= restTemplate.getForObject("myURL", Page.class);
    return page;
}
```

What I am missing? It looks that using private required classical lowerUpper convention but if I change that it won't be properly matched with the JSON. Can I name it somehow for spring?

```
//spring, this is PHONE
public String phone;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what are the getter and setter for PHONE and Website.May be the getter and setter do not have correct case .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use @JsonProperty annotation to override the variable name.

```
@JsonProperty("phone")
public String PHONE;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but in the result I had:both PHONE and phone. When I removed getters and setters it seems to be working. It means I should not have setters there? Or it is caused by something else?

Comment: have you added the annotation to the getter/setter method as well?

Comment: Basically, if its private then have getter and setter and annotate the variable declaration. Else, just annotating the variable declaration should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked. Just put @JsonProperty annotation on variable, getters, and setters and your restful can consume as well as produce the uppercase!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, helped me