# How to check if JSON Elements / Keys are valid using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets say you have JSON which are schema less and let's say you haved a class that looks like this:

```
public class Score {

    @JsonProperty("game-score")
    private int gameScore;

    @JsonProperty("high-score")
    private int highScore;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

So, lets say that that JSON looks like this:

```
{ "game-score": 100, "high_score":16000 }
```

When marshalling this JSON using Jackson, I receive the following from my Overriden toString() method (in which I placed the '{' and '}' explicitly):

```
{"game-score":100, "high-score": 0}
```

As you can see that the problem is the real property (for highScore) set has a "-" and the JSON being marshalled has a "_".

This causes the property to go to its default value when one invokes a toString() method or invokes a getHighscore() method from the Score class.

Question(s):

(1) Given a class that has specific @JsonProperty set, is there a way to parse a JSON String to check if it matches the @JsonProperty inside the POJO before or after the marshalling process and then setting a return boolean method to false?

(2) How to get all JSON names and values from a populated JsonNode using Jackson?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I need to do it in my own program... JsonLint doesn't know how to use @JsonProperty to check against JSON keys being formatted a specific way.

Comment: You need to know the how to use @JsonProperty:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for