# Boolean checkbox in Spring MVC + ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a boolean checkbox in my html page, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="pnrCheckbox" name="includesPnr" value="true"/>
<!-- this field is autogenerated by spring as a workaround for something -->
<input type="hidden" name="_includesPnr" value="on"/>
```

When I send a Json string via Ajax to my controller, network traffic in my browser shows this form data:

```
_includesPnr: on
```

In my controller I use Jackson to deserialize the json back to my java model, which fails because it cannot map the _includesPnr property because of the underscore. If I manually map the the property like this

```
@JsonProperty(value="_includesPnr")
private Boolean includesPnr;
```

it still fails because 'on' is not a boolean value.

What do I have to do to send the property with the correct name and true/false instead of on/off?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the @JsonProperty annotation:
[JSON field mapping for Java model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943675/json-field-mapping-for-java-model)

Then use a custom deserializer to convert "on" to "true"

In your case:

```
@JsonProperty("_includesPnr")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomBooleanDeserializer.class)
private Boolean includesPnr;
```

Then for CustomBooleanDeserializer (reference: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html)

```
public class CustomBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

   @Override
   public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
        DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws
    IOException, JsonProcessingException {
       return ("on".equals(jsonParser.getText())) ? true : false;
   }
}
```

(Code is untested)