# json parsing with resttemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I have a json response as below

```
{
    "@odata.context": "some context value here",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.id": "odata id value1",
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQEet/1EgOuA\"",
        "Id": "id1",
        "Subject": "subject1"
    }, {
        "@odata.id": "odata id value2",
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CyEet/1EgOEk1t/\"",
        "Id": "id2",
        "Subject": "subject2"
    }]
}
```

How do I create a bean class(MyMessage) to parse the "value" using spring resttemplate?

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<MyMessage> response = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, MyMessage.class);
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you need to handle this property yourself ? I think you don't need to map it, the OData server part will find it itself and do what needs to be done.

Comment: I am trying to use outlook mail api. They dont have a java client. https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Getmessages . On client, we need to parse this message to get mail details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate bean properties with `@JsonProperty` to set JSON field name for the property if it is different.

See:

[JsonProperty annotation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) and [When is the @JsonProperty property used and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Example (bean properties are public for example simplicity):

MyMessage class:

```
public class MyMessage {

    @JsonProperty("@odata.context")
    public String context;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Value[] values;
}
```

Value class:

```
// PascalCaseStrategy is to resolve Id and Subject properties
@JsonNaming(PascalCaseStrategy.class)
public class Value {

    @JsonProperty("@odata.id")
    public String odataId;

    @JsonProperty("@odata.etag")
    public String odataEtag;

    public String id;
    public String subject;
}
```