# SpringMVC response json not right for Boolean properties

Tags: java, json, spring

I use SpringMVC 4.2.5, and make a rest Controller, but the response is not what I want.
Here it's the detail.
I have an Entity named `propertyEntity`,

```
public class PropertyEntity implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7032855749875735832L;
    private int id;
    private String propertyName;
    private boolean isEnable;
    private boolean isDimension;
    private boolean isMetric;
}
```

and the Controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/properties")
public class PropertyController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<PropertyEntity> getAll() {
         return propertyService.getAll();
    }
}
```

When I request the api, the result is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "propertyName": "money1",
        "isEnable": true,
        "dimension": false,
        "metric": true
  },
  {
        "id": 2,
        "propertyName": "money2",
        "isEnable": true,
        "dimension": false,
        "metric": true
  } 
]
```

what I want is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "propertyName": "money1",
        "isEnable": true,
        "isDimension": false,
        "isMetric": true
  },
  {
        "id": 2,
        "propertyName": "money2",
        "isEnable": true,
        "isDimension": false,
        "isMetric": true
  } 
]
```

The unexpected thing is:
`isDimention` is changed to `dimension`,
`isMetric` is changed to `metric`,
but `isEnable` is right.

Comment: try using @JsonProperty("isEnable") over the field

Comment: Weird. That seems like a bug if only one of the properties behaves that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using jackson for converting the "PropertyEntity" object to a json.

A possible **problem here could be the getters and setters in PropertyEntity class.**

**See the getter/setter of `isEnable` and follow a similar naming convention for `isMetric` & `isDimension`**

ensure that the getters of boolean start with `isIsMetric()...` instead of `getIsMetric()`.

If this  does not help, please share your getters and setters over here.

Comment: Yes, it's the getters and setters method name, change to getIsMetric() and setIsMetric(boolean isMetric) solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to :

```
public class PropertyEntity implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    ...
    ...
    @JsonProperty("isEnable")
    private boolean isEnable;
    ...
    ...
}
```

See also :[When is the @JsonProperty property used and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12583638/2815219)

Comment: I tried adding @JsonProperty("isMetric"), yes, it turns out to `isMetric` result, but `metric` is still there, so I think the reason is what @ishanbakshi says. Thanks all the same, and for the useful link.