# How to deserialize multiple cases with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am working with jackson-core-2.8.3 and I have a json which has element provided in multiple cases. I want to map it to my class but I am not able to do so because I can have only one type of PropertyNamingStratergy in my class.

Example Json:-

```
{"tableKey": "1","not_allowed_pwd": 10}
```

There can be another json like

```
{"tableKey": "1","notAllowedPwd": 10}
```

ClassToMap :-

```
class MyClass {
public String tableKey;
public Integer notAllowedPwd;
}
```

ObjectMapper code :-

```
ObjectMapperobjectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES,true);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL,Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD,Visibility.ANY);
MyClass obj = objectMapper.readValue(s, MyClass.class);
```

I am not finding any solution anywhere. It will be good if anyone can help how to proceed.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: this link might help you http://websystique.com/java/json/jackson-json-annotations-example/

Comment: The problem is that json can vary call to call so snakecase can be camelcase format

Answer (score 0):

Use jackson-annotations library and add `@JsonProperty` as below.

```
class MyClass {
  public String tableKey;
  @JsonProperty("not_allowed_pwd")
  public Integer notAllowedPwd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have different requirement, I have edited the question.

Comment: In that case, you would either have to 1) map to two different classes and combine manually, or 2) fix the schema of your json. I don't think changing/inconsistent property names could be mapped effortlessly

Comment: Is there any class which is used during readValue method where I can modify property name to camelcase usinng my class

Answer (score 0):

You can have a second setter with a `@JsonProperty` annotation for the second field name:

```
class MyClass {
    private String tableKey;
    private Integer notAllowedPwd;

    public String getTableKey() {
        return tableKey;
    }

    public void setTableKey(String tableKey) {
        this.tableKey = tableKey;
    }

    public Integer getNotAllowedPwd() {
        return notAllowedPwd;
    }

    public void setNotAllowedPwd(Integer notAllowedPwd) {
        this.notAllowedPwd = notAllowedPwd;
    }

    @JsonProperty("not_allowed_pwd")
    public void setNotAllowedPwd2(Integer notAllowedPwd) {
        this.notAllowedPwd = notAllowedPwd;
    }
}
```

Take into consideration that if the two properties are present in the json, they will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Use these annotations on field:

```
@JsonProperty("not_allowed_pwd")
@JsonAlias("notAllowedPwd")
public Integer notAllowedPwd;
```