# Entity getter needs to end with "s" to be included in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data-rest

Im creating a RESTful API using Spring-data-rest. I have an entity;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pricingoptionsets") 
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@pricingOptionSetId") //To prevent fetch loops
public class PricingOptionSet {

//Region Properties
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="PricingOptionSetId", nullable=false, unique=true)
private Long pricingOptionSetId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ProductId")
private Product product;
```

Now on the Getters & Setters, If I have the following:

```
public Product getProducts() {
        return product;
    }
```

I receive the Product information in the JSON of the response. But if the getter is:

```
public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
```

Then Product information is not included anymore:S

Any ideas how to fix that? Btw, I'm using a simple repository that extends CRUDRepository

Comment: what does your setter and json look like?

Comment: Thats the JSON{
  "_embedded" : {
    "pricingOptionSets" : [ {
      "@pricingOptionSetId" : 1,
      "name" : "AgentRate30",
      "products" : {
        "@productId" : 4,
        "productId" : 1,
      },

And thats the setter:
public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here getProducts() is a method so it doesn't matter weather you define it as getProducts() or  getProduct() .

The only problem here which can happen is the implementation where you are using this method should also be changed in accordance with the method name.

Try this or else just post your json response for the same so we can figure out what the problem is but this is sure the method name don't have anything to do with response change.

Comment: Considering what you said, I can´t modify spring code so I guess they are expecting a getter in plural... eventho the relationship is not like that..

Comment: are you writting getter and setter or generating auto generated getter and setters ?

Comment: im using auto generated

Comment: Then use that auto generated getters and setters only don't try to modify it.

Comment: What response you are getting while using getProduct() ?

Comment: if I use the auto generated getProduct() i just get a link to the product

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your json

```
{ "_embedded" : { "pricingOptionSets" : [ { "@pricingOptionSetId" : 1, "name"
 : "AgentRate30", "products" : { "@productId" : 4, "productId" : 1, }
```

the property should be `products` so your need to have the setter and getter to be `getProducts` setProducts` - Of course it is desirable that the field should also match

You could also consider to use `@jsonProperty` as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12583772/2310289

In your case it would be

```
@JsonProperty(value="products")
private Product product;
```

Comment: But the property is Product because its only one product.

Comment: Alex, as a human you are correct, but the the JSON (which is probably wrong)  names it as `products`