# Why are underscores added to fields of a typescript class in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I am building an **Angular4** project and using **IntelliJ**. Whenever I create a new class, and then add **getters** and **setters**. The IDE adds underscores to the fields.

Being that typescript syntax seems to be recognised automatically by the IDE and yet creates the fields in this way, leaves me to think that this is a best practice, but I have also read that this should not be done.

Why does the IDE do this? And should I allow it to do this for an angular project? Thanks for any help!

Before creating the getters and setters

```
export class Test {


  hello:string;
  world:string;


}
```

After creating the getters and setters

```
export class Test {


  private _hello:string;
  private _world:string;

  get hello(): string {
    return this._hello;
  }

  set hello(value: string) {
    this._hello = value;
  }

  get world(): string {
    return this._world;
  }

  set world(value: string) {
    this._world = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post a code example?

Comment: @Maximus I have added a code example, the variable _hello was hello before I added the getter and setter.

Comment: private variables are started with `_` , nothing more than that

Comment: Probably worth noting that if you have a json object `const json = { "hello": "foo", "world": "bar" }` and `const baz = new Test()` then you can just do `Object.assign(baz, json)` and it will call the setters and correctly assign to the private `_hello` and `_world` attributes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The getter/setter cannot have the name that matches the property name - the following won't work:

```
class A {
   get world() {
      return this.world;
   }
}
```

So the general pattern is to name the internal properties just like a setter/getter only with the edition of an underscore:

```
class A {
   get world() {
      return this._world;
   }
}
```

Since JS and therefore TS lacks runtime encapsulation, an underscore usually signifies internal/private/encapsulated property/variable.

But nothing forces you to use underscores. If you name your getter/setter differently, you can avoid adding underscores:

```
class A {
   get getWorld() {
      return this.world;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have to say, that is annoying, because it means that at the API level of my rest service, I have to name all of the fields with an _  in the beginning in order for the deserialisation process to happen correctly. This is not a best practice in java which is the language used for the api.

Comment: Is there a best practice for addressing this issue?

Comment: what is annoying? IDE behavior or that you should have corresponding property name with an underscore?

Comment: It is annoying, because it means that at the API level of my rest service, I have to name all of the fields with an _ in the beginning in order for the deserialisation process to happen correctly

Comment: @Dan, see my updated answer, you don't have to use an underscore if you name accessors differently

Comment: Ok. Thanks. There has to be an IDE configuration to address this. I got what I was after though...Which was why does this happen. I will probably post something later about how I solve so that is in line with best practices for the API.

Comment: @Dan, you're welcome. It's the [same in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html), you have to name your getter/setter differently from the referenced class properties

Comment: If anybody is interested...This seems like a controversial issue. Here is a discussion about it. https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1108

Comment: Ive also found, that maybe the best solution would probably not touch typescript code at all, but in (in the case of java) use the jackson library and use the @JsonProperty annotation to define a json property and how it should be mapped to a java bean field. I think this is how we will solve the problem for our situation...Heres a small example which explains this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for .... In this way backend developers can be happy as well as the front end folk :)

Comment: Have worked with this again further... I still think that taking care of this at the api level is the best way to go....but another solution is to ovrride toJson() in the typescript class.

Comment: public toJSON(): Object {
    return new Object({
      hello: this.hello,
      world: this.world
    });
  }

Comment: I would strongly suggest against changing the server API to comply with these underscore parameters. This should be handled in the frontend. Better encapsulate it in a wrapper class over the HttpClient and include the DTO serialization that hides the underscores.

Comment: To summarize the https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1108 discussion, it was decided that the guideline was to drop the underscore for private member. The **ONE EXCEPTION** was for backing fields of defined properties. There, it still recommended to use the underscore prefix.

Comment: @CodeMaverick, yes, since TypeScript has access modifiers it doesn't make sense to use underscores. However, if a property is accessed through a setter/getter, naming corresponding property with an underscore is a good option

Comment: @Dan agree with you Dan. It's not only annoying but also ugly. It's unproductive on how it brakes models. The more I envolve with Angular, the more I convinced that is bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a different prefix to be used for fields in `Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Code Generation`, `Naming conventions/Field prefix`. But note that leaving the prefix empty will result in `TS2300:Duplicate identifier` errors

Comment: So you are saying that you have to have a prefix for each field in a typescript class? Therefore you would need to have the same prefix for each field of a class at the api level in order to deserialise properly?

Comment: @Dan or you could have some deserialisation code that maps the names. If you deserialise to local classes which have methods then you can't just use json objects directly so you would need some sort of mapping anyway. You could look at using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-typescript-mapper