# "Unsupported Media Type" in spring boot - Windows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl

I have a `User` class like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long userID;

    String eMail;

    String passwordHash;

    //ArrayList<ClassRoom>adminOf=new ArrayList<>();

    User() {}

    public User(String eMail, String passwordHash) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }
}
```

And in a `LoadDatabase` class I have :

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner initDatabase(UserRepository userRepository) {
    return args -> {
        log.info("Preloading " + userRepository.save(new User("admin@admin.com", "asdasd")));
        log.info("Preloading " + userRepository.save(new User("admin@admin.com", "12345")));
    };
}
```

Which give me this :

[image: spring boot pre-loading]

Now in when I give `curl -v localhost:8080/user` this command it gives me this :

[image: spring-boot curl get]

Which is pretty correct, although it gives me `email` instead of `eMail`.

But when I give

```
curl -X PUT localhost:8080/user/3 -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"passwordHash":"12345","email":"admin1@admin.com"}'
```

it says :

[image: spring-boot curl post]

Which is pretty horrific. I'm following [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/?fbclid=IwAR0nxJoVr5x6RM2zABUE-UJuSkv0IYH5EiOWZLfiKxf4A91N_aEb0dah2EM) tutorial.

And here is my `UserController` class:

```
package com.mua.cse616.Controller;


import com.mua.cse616.Model.User;
import com.mua.cse616.Model.UserNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation .*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
class UserController {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    UserController(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // Aggregate root

    @GetMapping("/user")
    List<User> all() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    User newUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        return repository.save(newUser);
    }

    // Single item

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    User one(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/user/{id}")
    User replaceUser(@RequestBody User newUser, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(employee -> {
                    employee.setEMail(newUser.getEMail());
                    employee.setPasswordHash(newUser.getPasswordHash());
                    return repository.save(employee);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newUser.setUserID(id);
                    return repository.save(newUser);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Put method after updating :

```
@PutMapping(path="/user/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
User replaceUser(@RequestBody User newUser, @PathVariable Long id) {

    return repository.findById(id)
            .map(employee -> {
                employee.setEMail(newUser.getEMail());
                employee.setPasswordHash(newUser.getPasswordHash());
                return repository.save(employee);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                newUser.setUserID(id);
                return repository.save(newUser);
            });
}
```

**Now there arise two questions**.

- Why `email` instead of `eMail`, what to do to get `eMail` instead of `email`
- How to `POST` correctly, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "*Why `email` instead of `eMail`, what to do to get `eMail` instead of email*" - That is how jackson behaves. There are annotations, e.g. `@JsonProperty`, to control its behaviour. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for) for details. --- "*How to `POST` correctly, what I'm doing wrong?*" - Have you tried to set `@PutMapping(..., consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, ...)`?  --- A remark: please limit yourself to one question per post in the future.

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: From next time I will try to keep that in mind...
I'm on windows 10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Why `email` instead of `eMail`*" - That is just the default behavior of Jackson.

"*what to do to get `eMail` instead of `email`*" - You can control Jackson's behavior through annotations on the POJO. The relevant here is `@JsonProperty`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for) for details.

"*How to `POST` correctly, what I'm doing wrong?*" - You mean `PUT` instead of `POST`, don't you? Define the content type consumed by the method:

```
@PutMapping(path="/user/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
User replaceUser(@RequestBody User newUser, @PathVariable Long id) {
    ...
}
```

Also, as was pointed out by @rimonmostafiz, you need to redefine your `curl` call, escaping the quotation:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"asd\", \"passwordHash\": \"sad\" }"
```

As an aside: Please [limit yourself to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Add missing `consumes` attribute on `@PutMapping` annotation,

```
@PutMapping(path= "/user/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
User replaceUser(@RequestBody User newUser, @PathVariable Long id) {
```

> although it gives me email instead of eMail

It all depends on your `getter/setter` of property `eMail` in your `User` entity. I think your getter must be `getEmail()` and hence conventionally you get in response email as JSON property.

Comment: The `path` setting worked but ...still gives me error .. Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZMT.png)


Command was : `curl -X POST localhost:8080/user -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"passwordHash":"12345","email":"adminasd@admin.com"}'`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad you are `PUT`ing on the wrong endpoint (`/3` is missing in the url...)

Comment: You are not using correct API. Your logs says you are using API /user with POST method. Your questions is for /user/{id} and PUT.

Comment: `PUT` doesn't work too...
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxhO2.png) is the result...
It says : `"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'PUT' not supported","path":"/user"`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad please elaborate and show us what you mean exactly

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad again, you are `PUT`ing on the wrong enpoint. Try `curl -X PUT localhost:8080/user/3 -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"passwordHash":"12345","email":"adminasd@admin.com"}'`

Comment: @Turing85 it gives me : `{"timestamp":"2019-07-28T07:30:16.766+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/user/3"}`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad again you are not using correct API endpoint. Please refer to correct API. /user/{id} with PUT method is correct API.

Comment: Both doesn't work... Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2eWI.png)... One says `Request method 'POST' not supported`, other says `Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad have you tried substituting `'` with `"` in your `curl` command as was suggested by @rimonmostafiz?

Comment: ... and this is why we do not post speculative answers. All this discussion should be on the question, not on this answer...

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad ' is not an issue. Show your PUT API after suggested answer.

Comment: try substituting `Content-type`with `Content-Type` in your `curl` call.

Comment: I have given the new API in question , please see... as is is quite big and messy for question ..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad your update to PUT is fine. Check rimonmostafiz suggestion for curl command. I think after that it should solve your issue.